# How to fill quadratic curve in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible to fill quadratic curve?

I am newbie in canvas and I'd like to fill the color of the upper part of what I have drawn in context.quadraticCurveTo(), but when I tried the context.fill() it does not fill my expected section. I'd like to fill in the upper part of the canvas which was separated by the stroke.

See attached snippet.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const ch = canvas.height;
const cw = canvas.width;

// Quadratic Bézier curve
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 60);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ch, 0, cw, 35);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just drawing some lines along the canvas edge to make a closed shape:

[image]

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const ch = canvas.height;
const cw = canvas.width;

// Quadratic Bézier curve
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 60);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ch, 0, cw, 35);
ctx.lineTo(cw, 0);   // these two lines
ctx.lineTo(0, 0);    // are new
                     // you can even add a third one that goes from 0,0
                     // to 0,60 … but .fill() closes the shape even without it
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```